# C# Microsoft.Data.Analysis Dataframe to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataframe, entity-framework

I want to load my Microsoft.Data.Analysis Dataframe into a SQL Server table. I somehow learnt that I should use Entity Framework for that, but I haven't found a solution similar to Pythons Sqlalchemy pandas.dataframe.tosql() method. Is there an easy way to achieve that?

I've already tried Googling that of course, but sadly that did not lead to any results, is it possible at all?

Thanks in advance for any help and have a lovely day

Comment: Right now, no. The `Microsoft.Data.Analysis` namespace is somewhat ... aspirational and can't even be used to *load* data from a database. It's an attempt to create something like Pandas Dataframes in the future and has nothing at all to do with Entity Framework.

Comment: Thanks alot:) so what would you recommend me using? The code im editing is sadly having it stored in a dataframe, is there an easy way to move the data into something that can interact with an SQL server?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve in the first place? If you have working Python code, why not keep using it? Sure, reading Excel files is 10 times slower, but *that* isn't supported with Microsoft.Data.Analysis either. You can keep using the Notebooks and tools you already have, which are formidable. Never mind that Python is better supported in both Visual Studio Code and Azure Data Studio

Comment: I've been working with .NET since 2003-ish. 8 months ago I had to work with a ton of Excel files coming from 40 different sources that couldn't use the same columns even though they contained similar data. I started using Python, Pandas and Notebooks because, no matter how slow loading is, trying to handle the myriad minor differences with .NET would take forever. I already knew how to load Excel files using eg ExcelDataReader and how long it would take to handle it's slightly different file.

Answer (score 6):

Right now, no. The `Microsoft.Data.Analysis` namespace is somewhat ... aspirational and can't even be used to *load* data from a database. It's an attempt to create something like Pandas Dataframes in the future and has nothing at all to do with Entity Framework.

If you want a DataFrame-like type in .NET, check the [Deedle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Deedle) library which is used in F# data analysis programming.

Another option is to keep using Python, or learn Python, Pandas and Notebooks. Even Visual Studio Code and Azure Data Studio offer better support for Pandas and Notebooks than Microsoft.Data.Analysis.

---

The problem is that until recently Microsoft put all its effort in ML, not analysis. And [Microsoft.Data.Analysis](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/tree/main/src/Microsoft.Data.Analysis) is part of the [ML repository](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/tree/main/src/), so it got little attention since its introduction 2 years ago.

This changed on March 2022, when the [DataFrame (Microsoft.Data.Analysis) Tracking Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/6144) was created to track and prioritize what programmers wanted from a .NET Dataframe type. [Loading from a database](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/5662) is open for 2 years without progress.

**Loading from SQL**

If you want to use `Microsoft.Data.Analysis.DataFrame` right now you'll have to write code [similar to the CSV loading code](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Data.Analysis/DataFrame.IO.cs#L199):

- Create [a list of DataFrameColumn](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Data.Analysis/DataFrame.IO.cs#L210)s from a DataReader's schema. This can be retrieved with  [DbDataReader.GetSchemaTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getschematable?view=net-6.0).
- [Create a DataFrame with those columns](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Data.Analysis/DataFrame.IO.cs#L268)
- For each row, [append the list of values](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Data.Analysis/DataFrame.IO.cs#L285) to the dataframe. The values could be retrieved with [DbDataReader.GetValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getvalues?view=net-6.0)

**Loading from Excel**

The same technique can be used if the Excel file is loaded using a library like ExcelDataReader that exposed the data through a DataReader. The library doesn't implement all methods though, so some tweaking may be needed if eg `GetValues` doesn't work.

**Writing to SQL**

That's harder because you can't just send a stream of rows to a table. A DataFrame is a collection of Series too, not rows. You'd have to construct the `INSERT` SQL command from the column names, then execute it with data from each row.

A dirty way would be to convert the DataFrame into a DataTable and save that using a DataAdapter. That would create yet another copy of the data in memory though.

A better way would be to create a DataReader wrapper over a DataFrame, and pass that reader to eg SqlBulkCopy

Comment: Loading from SQL is a little easier now with `DataFrame.LoadFrom(DbDataReader)` [link](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/d96d7b741eadb5c8ba65e14c912cea48ce311f36/src/Microsoft.Data.Analysis/DataFrame.IO.cs#L199)

Comment: Emphasis on `little`. The CSV functionality isn't flexible and is actually the slowest among CSV parsers, `LoadFrom` means you need an external driver or to write your own IO code. The rich format support of Pandas or Polars is missing. VS Code and Azure Data Studio Notebooks still aren't sure whether they use DataFrame or not. Lazy loading functionality seems to be possible using ML.NET views. Finally the docs just aren't there.